# Simplifying an object created using map

Tags: javascript, arrays

Does anyone know how I can simplify this code, especially the definition of the variable `codes`?

```
const numbers = [
  { id1: 1, id2: 2, id3: 3, pos: "a" },
  { id1: 4, id2: 5, id3: 6, pos: "b" },
  { id1: 7, id2: 8, id3: 9, pos: "c" }
];

let codes = {
  id1: Math.max.apply(
    Math,
    numbers.map((n) => {
      return n.id1;
    })
  ),
  id2: Math.max.apply(
    Math,
    numbers.map((n) => {
      return n.id2;
    })
  ),
  id3: Math.max.apply(
    Math,
    numbers.map((n) => {
      return n.id3;
    })
  )
};

console.log(codes);
```

I want to reduce the number of lines in this, but I have to keep this exact same data structure. I don't know where to apply a loop, or if that's possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the number of answers you get in a short time, you can measure how much research has been lacking before posting this question.

Answer (score 3):

Take the `id` keys and use `Object.fromEntries` to map each key to an array of that key, and `Math.max` called on the `numbers` mapped to that key:

```js
const numbers = [
  { id1: 1, id2: 2, id3: 3, pos: "a" },
  { id1: 4, id2: 5, id3: 6, pos: "b" },
  { id1: 7, id2: 8, id3: 9, pos: "c" }
];
const codes = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.keys(numbers[0]).slice(0, 3).map(
    key => ([
      key,
      Math.max(...numbers.map(obj => obj[key]))
    ])
  )
);
console.log(codes);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a dynamic approach by having an array of the wanted keys.

```js
const numbers = [{ id1: 1, id2: 2, id3: 3, pos: "a" }, { id1: 4, id2: 5, id3: 6, pos: "b" }, { id1: 7, id2: 8, id3: 9, pos: "c" }],
    keys = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'],
    codes = numbers.reduce((r, o) => {
        keys.forEach(k => r[k] = Math.max(k in r ? r[k]: -Infinity, o[k]));
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(codes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple loops over the keys

```js
const numbers = [
  { id1: 1, id2: 2, id3: 3, pos: "a" },
  { id1: 4, id2: 5, id3: 6, pos: "b" },
  { id1: 7, id2: 8, id3: 9, pos: "c" }
];

const max = {};
numbers.forEach(row =>
  Object.entries(row).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (max[key] === undefined || value > max[key]) max[key] = value;
  })
);

console.log(max);
```

if you just want to loop over certain props, loop over an array of keys instead of the object itself.

```js
const numbers = [
  { id1: 1, id2: 2, id3: 3, pos: "a" },
  { id1: 4, id2: 5, id3: 6, pos: "b" },
  { id1: 7, id2: 8, id3: 9, pos: "c" }
];

var maxFields = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];

const max = {};
numbers.forEach(row =>
  maxFields.forEach(key => {
    if (max[key] === undefined || row[key] > max[key]) max[key] = row[key];
  })
);

console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic for loop will also work

```
let codes = {};
for(let i=1; i<= 3; i++){
    codes['id' + i] = Math.max.apply(Math, numbers.map(n => n['id' + i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the prop you want to calculate

```js
const numbers = [
  { id1: 1, id2: 2, id3: 3, pos: "a" },
  { id1: 4, id2: 5, id3: 6, pos: "b" },
  { id1: 7, id2: 8, id3: 9, pos: "c" },
]

const props = ["id1", "id2", "id3"]

let codes = Object.fromEntries(
  props.map((prop) => [
    prop,
    Math.max(...numbers.map((number) => number[prop])),
  ])
)

console.log(codes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing in my version:

```js
const numbers = [
    { id1: 1, id2: 2, id3: 3, pos: "a" },
    { id1: 4, id2: 5, id3: 6, pos: "b" },
    { id1: 7, id2: 8, id3: 9, pos: "c" }
];

let codes = {};
['id1', 'id2', 'id3'].forEach(id => {
    codes[id] = Math.max.apply(
        Math,
        numbers.map(n => n[id])
    )
});

console.log(codes);
```